# How to solve this error "Error in nchar(homeDir) : invalid multibyte string, element 1"

Tags: r

I am getting below error when I am trying to load/ install any packages. This happened when installed new version of .

```r
Error in nchar(homeDir) : invalid multibyte string, element 1
In addition: Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
    path[1]="C:/Users/my.name/OneDrive - companies name/Documents":
        The system cannot find the path specified
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to SO!, I think you forgot to tell us the name of the package you try to install.
Could you also share the code you typed to try the installation? At this moment there is only a error message, but without the code and the name of the package there is not enough information to help you with the problem.

Comment: What version of R are you using? Using OneDrive for libraries is not really a great idea. The latest version of R tries to your AppDir folder rather than your documents folder which would probably work out better.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I re-installed my OneDrive. I solved it by unlinking the Documents folder of my desktop from OneDrive. You can check in the following link how to do this:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/unlink-my-documents-folder-from-onedrive/21edbce4-a38e-489b-8aab-608f0f4ee506?page=2